# when i write name id to show option from db Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#

```
            SqlConnection tr = new SqlConnection("Data source =MR-GHOST\\SQLEXPRESS ; DataBase =trdatabase; Integrated Security= true;");
            SqlCommand cmd; // بمكننا من تعدبل على الداتا حذف اضاقة تعديل من خلال برنامج 
            SqlDataReader red;

            private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
             try 
             { 
              cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Title , Author , Publish_date ,pages From books_tables Where ID='"+textBox1+"'",tr);
              // select هو الاستعلام الخاص ب البحث
              tr.Open();
              red = cmd.ExecuteReader();    //نربط داتا ريدر ب سمد لتنفيد الكوموند
              red.Read();    // نفوم ب عملبة القراءة
              textTitle.Text = red["Title"].ToString();
              textAuthor.Text = red["Author"].ToString();
              textdate.Text = red["publish_date"].ToString();
              textpages.Text = red["pages"].ToString();
             }
             catch(SqlException pro)
             {
                MessageBox.Show(pro.Message,"error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
             }
             finally
             {
                tr.Close();
                red.Close();
             }
```

Comment: Based on what you have provided you likely want to use textBox1.Text, that said I would look into parameterized SQL as what you're doing currently is not a very good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

textBox1 is an object of type `TextBox`.

When you add a string with an object, it will automatically call the corresponding .ToString method for that object, in which case it returns something like this             `"System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: "`.

So your command looks like, `"SELECT ... ID='System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: [WITHYOURTEXTHERE]'"`

You should use textBox1.Text instead.